# Angular unit test subscribe method with Jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I'm new at unit test with angular and jest, I'm trying to test this method:

```
doSearch(pageSize?:number) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    const formClone = this.form?.getRawValue();
    this.splitStringToGetOnlyTheId(formClone);
    this.onCheckEmptyFieldsAndReplaceNull(formClone);

   
    this._userService?.getUsers(formClone, pageSize)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.dataSource = response.content;
        this.agGrid?.api.setRowData(this.dataSource);
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.isShowingTable = true;
      }
  }
```

so I tried using jest spyOn method, but with no sucess:
See the code below:

```
  describe('UserComponent', () => {
  let component: UserComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserComponent>
  let mockUserService: UserService;


  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ UserComponent ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService },
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    mockUserService = TestBed.inject(UserService);

  });

  it('should return some value after doSearch', () => {
    const mockresponse = {
      content: [{
        businessUnitId: '0800',
        firstName: 'teste',
        lastName: 'lastteste',
        mail: 'teste@gmail.com',
        isActive: true,
      }],
    }
    const spysplit = jest.spyOn(component, 'splitStringToGetOnlyTheId');
    const spycheck = jest.spyOn(component, 'onCheckEmptyFieldsAndReplaceNull');
    const spyService = jest.spyOn(mockUserService, 'getUsers').mockReturnValue(of(mockresponse));

    component.doSearch();
    expect(spysplit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spycheck).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spyService).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given

I don't understand, I'm spying on the method already.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from the Unit Test perspective, spy those two methods

```
this.splitStringToGetOnlyTheId(formClone);
this.onCheckEmptyFieldsAndReplaceNull(formClone);
```

makes no sence, since them will be called anyway, probably, you will need to check the consecuence, if there's any.

Following that approach, you don't need to assert the service call, the test should expect that

```
this.dataSource
```

is filled with the mocked data, something like:

```
expect(component.dataSource).toBe(mockresponse.content);
```

**EDIT 1**

With just that expect, and removing the leftover spies, the test should pass:

```
it('should return some value after doSearch', () => {
const mockresponse = {
  content: [{
    businessUnitId: '0800',
    firstName: 'teste',
    lastName: 'lastteste',
    mail: 'teste@gmail.com',
    isActive: true,
  }],
}
jest.spyOn(mockUserService, 'getUsers').mockReturnValue(of(mockresponse));

component.doSearch();

expect(component.dataSource).toBe(mockresponse.content);
});
```

**EDIT 2**

Also, in your test configuration you are providing the UserService using an undefined variable, that's probably the reasin of the error, to solve it you have two options:

1. If the service is provided in root you don't need to provide it in the test.
2. If it's not provided in root you will need to create an instance of the service and provide it:

   let mockUserService: UserService = new UserService(args...);

Comment: I didn't understand, should I remove the mock form my service? and should not spy anymore?

Comment: You just need to spy the service to mock the response, but not expect it to be called

Comment: I tried but I still got the same error.

Comment: I saw the real problem, you are providing a null service for the Test. Answare updated